# Can you publish a personal feed to Facebook?

Tags: facebook

Somewhere in the Facebook APIs, is there an ability to publish a stream of events that will only be seen by a specific user in his feed (unless he shares them?)

We want to tailor the experience of each user separately.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this, you need to reference the documentation given [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post). To summarize it, you need to set the `privacy` parameter to something like this:

```
privacy={"value": "CUSTOM", "friends": "SOME_FRIENDS", "allow": "COMMA SEPARATED LIST OF FRIEND'S UIDS"}
```